# Criar Novo metodo em Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Como eu faço para criar um método no Rails que faça uma consulta no banco de dados em uma determinada tabela e mostre na `View`, e como eu faço para chamar esse método e onde criar?

```
def somar    
  @value = Registro.sum('saldo')
end
```

Como eu faço para chamar esse método na `view` e colocar em uma `label` ?

Comment: Desculpe, mas existem inúmeras formas de se chegar a este resultado, você pode ser mais específico editando e reformulando sua questão para que possamos responder de uma forma específica? Adicionar a sua principal dificuldade na questão também ajuda. Abraços.

Answer (score 1):

Bom vou considerar que você já tenha o Rails devidamente instalado e configurado em sua máquina.

Não ficou claro se seu método é realmente um método de **Modelo** ou uma `action` (um método de **Controller**), mas julgo ser uma `action`, pois você está chamando um método que, provavelmente é um método de um **Modelo**. Bom considerando essas suposições corretas podemos realizar os seguintes passos para que isso funcione.

Criamos nosso `Controller` e nossa `action` (utilizaremos `generator` para agilizar o procedimento)

> rails g controller operacoes somar

Que vai gerar nosso `controller` em `app/controllers/operacoes_controler.rb`

```
class OperacoesController < ApplicationController
  def somar
  end
end
```

E vai gerar nossa view em `app/views/operacoes/somar.html.erb`

```
<h1>Operacoes#somar</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/operacoes/somar.html.erb</p>
```

Ok agora estamos quase lá, não conheço seu `model` `Registro`, nem o que deseja somar, vou considerar que ele tenha um campo `saldo` e você quer somar o valor de cada `saldo` em todos os **registros**.

*** Para teste gerei o `model` `Registro`, mas provavelmente você não precisará realizar esse passo, colocarei aqui para demonstrar como realizei o procedimento.

> rails g model registro saldo:integer

*** No console criei 3 registros para testar a lógica, o que provavelmente você não precisará realizar também.

```
2.3.1 :001 > Registro.create(saldo: 1)
 => #<Registro id: 1, saldo: 1, created_at: "2016-07-14 23:56:46", updated_at: "2016-07-14 23:56:46"> 

2.3.1 :002 > Registro.create(saldo: 2)
 => #<Registro id: 2, saldo: 2, created_at: "2016-07-14 23:56:50", updated_at: "2016-07-14 23:56:50"> 

2.3.1 :003 > Registro.create(saldo: 3)
 => #<Registro id: 3, saldo: 3, created_at: "2016-07-14 23:56:53", updated_at: "2016-07-14 23:56:53">
```

### Resolução da pergunta

Coloque a atribuição do valor na `action` de `OperacoesController`

```
class OperacoesController < ApplicationController
  def somar
    @valor = Registro.sum('saldo')
  end
end
```

E coloque o `@valor` entre `tags erb` `<%= @valor =%>` em sua View (`app/views/operacoes/somar.html.erb`). Exemplo:

```
<h1>A soma dos saldos de todos os registros é <%= @valor %>  </h1>
```

Acesse: `http://localhost:3000/operacoes/somar`

E o resultado vai ser algo parecido com isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**EDIT:**
Caso queria re-utilizar esse método em diversas `Views` pode-se utilizar um `Helper` como o Rafael citou. Ou seja, remova do `OperacoesController` e adicione no `ApplicationHelper`, ex:

```
# /app/helpers/application_helper.rb
module ApplicationHelper
  def saldo_total
    Registro.sum('saldo')
  end
end
```

em sua View ficaria assim

```
#app/views/operacoes/index.html.erb
 <h1>A soma dos saldos de todos os registros é <%= saldo_total %>  </h1>
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado aos 2 que contribuíram, em especial ao Luiz , foi excelente sua explicação, consegui resolve meu problema....Ao Rafael agradeço e como já consegui com ajuda do luiz, da proxima vez tentarei ser mais claro...obg

Comment: @Juliano se a resposta foi satisfatória, marque como aceita. Bons estudos.

Comment: pegando o gancho , criei conforme vc explicou e deu certo, mas se eu quiser chamar esse metodo em uma outra view qualquer, exemplo colocar o resultado desse metodo dentro de uma label na classe index, como eu poderia chamar esse metodo ...tentei ...
Dentro da view index e não foi ...
<> Saldo do Banco e  <%=@saldo %> </h3>

controller criado para o calculo...

class OperationsController < ApplicationController
  def consult_balance
   @saldo = Registro.where(:data => Date.new(2016,06,1) .. Date.today).sum('saldo')
  end
end

Comment: @Juliano neste caso você vai precisar definir seus métodos dentro dos helpers que se localizam na pasta **app/helpers** (vai notar que existe um helper para a aplicação geral, e um helper para cada controller). Posso te indicar um livro que li recentemente e me guiou do zero ao intermediario no Ruby on Rails? segue o [link](https://www.railstutorial.org/book).

Comment: muito obr verei o livro e obrigado pela dica....me ajudou muito!

Comment: @Juliano editei a pergunta respondendo seu questionamento. Novamente incentive os usuários que te ajudam Votando em suas perguntas e aceitando a como resposta. Por favor leia: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers e sejam bem vindo a comunidade.

Answer (score 0):

Neste caso você vai precisar definir seu método em um helper. Helpers são classes com métodos auxiliares disponíveis nas views e também nos controllers (através de #helpers), como mostra a tabela 1.

```
module ApplicationHelper
    def identity(user)
        return "#{user.name} - #{user.email}"
    end
end
```

*Tabela 1. Código com um método auxiliar de exemplo.*

Ninguém vai explicar melhor do que a própria sessão sobre helpers na documentação oficial do Ruby on Rails, segue o [link](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Helpers.html), recomendo uma leitura completa (mesmo que inglês, a leitura é fácil).